# You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information

Tags: php, symfony

I wanted to install a control panel, but when I want to access a file

> http://admin.domain.com/app_dev.php

I get this error :

> You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information.

*File content*

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
// If you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup
// for more information
//umask(0000);
// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])

    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))

 {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}

/** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
Debug::enable();

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I use Namecheap shared hosting

Comment: Look at the two lines above the isset. It says you can remove that section if you want, or you can just comment it out if you want to try to use it or tweak it later.

Comment: I did it and did not work

Comment: You shouldn't be attempting to access the app_dev.php file outside local development. It enables debugging and is a security risk in production. The file has some built in security to prevent what you're attempting. Run the site locally to use the app_dev.php file.

Answer (score 2):

you have to comment this part of code :

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])

    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))

 {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```